# How to solve the follwing inequality? some conditions of parameters.

Tags: computational-mathematics

Assume that the following inequation exist. How can I get the condition of parameters?

$$(b_1-\frac{1}{2}u_1)u_1\geq (u_1+u_2)(t-t_0)+x_0$$

$$u_1\in[0,b_1]$$ $$u_2\in [0,b_2]$$ $$x_0\geq0$$ and $b_1,b_2$ is a constant

Numerical solution, $$b_1=400, b_2=500, t_0=0, x_0=0$$, I still didn't find the solution? The left side is a number, the right side is a function of t, so there don't have a solution?

$$(400-u_1)u_1\geq (u_1+u_2)*t,u_1\in [0,400], u_2\in [0,400]$$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Aren't you just trying to rearrange this to get an inequality for $t$?

Comment: Yeah, from my mind, except t, other thing are parameters in which we can given.